# Gsuite/GCP Azure SAML integration Returning "Invalid Email - We are unable to process your request at this time, please try again later"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml, google-workspace

Just wondering if anyone has experienced the following issue with SSO authentication.

**Overview:**
So, I setup Gsute/GCP SSO App in Azure to auto provision guest users/group in Gsuite. The Auto provision works just fine with for both users/SG.

***Issue:**
I notice that all guest users are in the following format in Azure:

```
user_domain.com#EXT#@tenant.onmicrosoft.com
```

They're able to athenticate in Azure just fine, but when they try to connect to Gsuite they receive the following message :

[image]

Just wondering if anyone may have experienced similar issue and how they resolved. This is what I think is the issue, when I manually create a user in gsuite the principlename looks like this: **user@student.xyz.com** however, if I auto provision this user from Azure, it looks like this: **user_emaildomain.com@student.xyz.com**

Note: In my SSO I have a user attributes claim that uses "**ExtractMailPrefix()**" transformation with a parameter of "**user.mail**" **Join()** with @ separator then "**student.xyz.com"** [image]

**Question**: Does any one know I can configure this to not include _emaildomain.com when extracting the mailPrefix to join to the student.xyz.com?

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this issue. the problem is you need to add the domain(student.xyz.com) from your GCP to azure ad so the users that are created will have the same domain(student.xyz.com)name as GCP. Right now you have the default domain.

this link will talk you through the process of adding the domain to azure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain

Google does not allow you to use emails outside the organization's domain

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little stale but as I've worked with the Claims Transformations in Azure, implementing dozens of SAML connectors with various Claims (attribute passing) rules, as of late 2021 I do not believe there is a combination of Azure AD Claims Transformation functions that will strip off just the username.  The "ExtractMailPrefix" function you are using just returns everything to the left of an "@" delimiter.  There is no function to substring from position 1 to the location before any "_" (assuming valid usernames in "emaildomain" could not contain any "_" to begin with, before hitting the start of the "emaildomain" string).